# Duplicate list on mobile site lacks formatting

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, mobile-web

When closing a question as a duplicate on the mobile version of the site, the lack of formatting of the list of similar questions is rather painful:

[image]

(apologies for the image size and the lack of freehand circles; I'm on mobile ...)

Comment: I'm fairly sure... Oops, this hasn't been asked before.

Comment: Mobile web is going away soon-ish, so...